# Is there a way to silence Ruby's deprecation warning in 2.4.0?

Tags: ruby, deprecation-warning

Since Ruby 2.4.0, there has been a deprecation warning for using certain features that have been deprecated. For example, `Bignum`, `Fixnum`, `TRUE`, and `FALSE` will all trigger deprecation warnings. While I'm fixing my code, there is a fair amount of code that I would like it silenced for, especially in Rails. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Silencing Deprecation warnings in Rails 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689377/silencing-deprecation-warnings-in-rails-3)

Comment: @Anthony This is different. Deprecation Warnings are in Ruby 2.4.0 now, not just Rails.

Comment: Would running your code with `-W0` option work here?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko For code that I write, but not for stuff that's baked deep in a gem.

Comment: check [this](http://www.caliban.org/ruby/rubyguide.shtml#warnings) and [this](http://mislav.net/2011/06/ruby-verbose-mode/) out

Comment: Also, there's a [gem ruby-warning](https://github.com/jeremyevans/ruby-warning) (never used it though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
module Kernel
  def suppress_warnings
    original_verbosity = $VERBOSE
    $VERBOSE = nil
    result = yield
    $VERBOSE = original_verbosity
    return result
  end
end


>> X = :foo
=> :foo
>> X = :bar
(irb):11: warning: already initialized constant X
=> :bar
>> suppress_warnings { X = :baz }
=> :baz
```

Comment: This is good for code that I've written, but is there a way to get Ruby to run all code like this on the whole?